# Why my UserControl using a Path as ControlTemplate is not properly clickable?

Tags: wpf, xaml, user-controls, controltemplate, hittest

I created a class derived from UserControl, directly on code (without XAML), and defined a ControlTemplate in a ResourceDictionary. This control template is a pair of ellipses, as follows:

```
<ControlTemplate x:Key="MusclePositionControlTemplate" TargetType="{x:Type local:MusclePositionControl}">
    <ControlTemplate.Resources>
        <EllipseGeometry x:Key="bolinha" RadiusX="{StaticResource radius}" RadiusY="{StaticResource radius}">
            <EllipseGeometry.Center>
                <Point X="0" Y="{StaticResource distance}"/>
            </EllipseGeometry.Center>
        </EllipseGeometry>                      
    </ControlTemplate.Resources>
        <Path Fill="#9900ffff" StrokeThickness="1" Stroke="Black">
            <Path.Data>
                <GeometryGroup>
                    <StaticResource ResourceKey="bolinha"/>
                    <GeometryGroup>
                        <GeometryGroup.Transform>
                            <ScaleTransform ScaleY="-1"/>
                        </GeometryGroup.Transform>
                        <StaticResource ResourceKey="bolinha"/>
                    </GeometryGroup>
                </GeometryGroup>                                
            </Path.Data>        
            <Path.RenderTransform>
                <TransformGroup>
                    <RotateTransform Angle="{Binding Angle, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=TemplatedParent}}"/>
                    <TranslateTransform
                        X="{Binding X, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=TemplatedParent}}"
                        Y="{Binding Y, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=TemplatedParent}}"/>
                </TransformGroup>               
            </Path.RenderTransform>
        </Path>
</ControlTemplate>
```

When I edit this template in Blend, I can select the path clicking on it, and it displays its outlines like this:

[image]

But when I add the actual control to a canvas, with its `X`, `Y` and `Angle` properties set to some value, the control renders itself fine, but its defining geometry keeps being that of a rectangle at the origin, and this affects hit testing (I cannot select at design time, or click at runtime, by clicking at the shape itself):

[image]

So my questions are:

1. How should I create a `ControlTemplate` using a Path as "root" visual element, so that the clickable area of the control is that Path?
2. Assuming a Path should not or could not be used as root visual for a ControlTemplate, how should I achieve the same end result?

Comment: Why inherit from `UserControl`? Wouldn't it be better to inherit from `Control` directly? You're not really making any use of UserControl's custom logic, which may (or may not) be responsible of that weird behavior you're seeing.

Comment: @almulo Well, I have just changed the base class to Control, as you suggested, but the behavior is still the same.